# How to remove an rpm package while keeping certain files

Tags: rhel, yum, rpm

Had an issue where 64-bit and 32-bit `httpd` packages were installed.

When one of the packages is uninstalled via `yum remove`, it removes certain shared files like `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`.

Is there a way to exclude removal of files via either `rpm` or `yum`? I looked at both `man`pages but couldn't see any relevant options.

*BTW: I'm aware we could backup the files and reinstate them after the uninstall. I just wanted to know if there's a cleaner, more elegant option.*

Comment: modified config files are usually left after a `yum remove` but leaving them in all cases might prove difficult. they are part of the package and operate in accordance with the `spec` file. Basically, it is rpm specific.

Comment: Ah okay. So no way to ignore part of the spec on uninstall?

Comment: i am not very knowledgeable about creating RPMs. you would probably have to rebuild the RPM, uninstall and reinstall the new RPM after you change the `spec`. basically too much work...

Comment: @BelminFernandez, regarding config files of the RPM; you can query them with "rpm -qc <package>" to get a list. If the RPM removal is also removing config files, you could query the package ahead of time and copy those files somewhere safe before removing the package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the package(s) were configured so that the httpd.conf file(s) were not declared to be "config" files, so they were not saved when the package(s) were removed. If httpd.conf had been declared as a config file and it was changed after installation, then it would have been saved as httpd.conf.rpmsave during package removal. See http://ftp.rpm.org/max-rpm/ch-rpm-erase.html for the steps taken during package removal.

You would have to predict this situation ahead of time in order to prepare for it -- either with file backup & recovery, as you mentioned, or by querying the package for its config files with `rpm -qc <package>`.

- If you queried the package(s) for their config files and did *not* find httpd.conf among them, then you can expect that file to get removed during package removal, and could copy it somewhere safe ahead of time.
- If the package(s) *did* list httpd.conf as a config file, then either: (1) you had made a meaningful change to the file, and it would be preserved during package removal, or (2) the file was unchanged since the package's installation and would be (harmlessly) removed during package removal.

Answer (score 2):

Not ideal, but I just solved a similar problem with `rpm -e --justdb` to record pkg as deleted without removing files.
I have old `rpm` v4.4.2.3 where `man rpm` lists `--justdb` only in installation section and not in removal, but it does work for removal as well.

Overview:

- make lists of files claimed by each pkg
- remove outgoing pkg from DB without removing content with `rpm -e --justdb PKG`
- tidy up, remove files that were claimed by removed pkg but not claimed by remaining pkg

Prepare

```
pkg_keep="asterisk-core-1.6.2.24-1_centos5"
pkg_del="asterisk16-core-1.6.2.20-2_centos5"

# Record files claimed by each package
rpm -ql "${pkg_del}" > "files.${pkg_del}"
rpm -ql "${pkg_keep}" > "files.${pkg_keep}"
```

Make list of files that are claimed by the outgoing pkg but not claimed by the remaining pkg.
**WARNING:** `--line-regexp` is important so e.g. `/file` does not filter out `/file2`.

```
grep -v -F --line-regexp -f "files.${pkg_keep}" "files.${pkg_del}" > files.cleanup
```

Remove outgoing PKG from RPM DB without removing its files.
It is unclear from the `man rpm` if `--noscripts` is implied with `--justdb`.
Also `--nodeps` might be needed.

```
rpm -e --justdb --noscripts "${pkg_del}"
```

Review **CAREFULLY** content of `files.cleanup`, and delete files listed there.

While you can automatically delete the files listed in `files.cleanup` IMO giving a command to do it here might hurt copy/paste reader.

Also, using something like `etckeeper` can help if all you are concerned about is under `/etc/`.

Comment: Thank you for sharing, I never know this is possible!

Answer (score 1):

Sadly (or fortunately, depends how you see it) there's no such thing as selective file removal. What I'd propose is to list the files, the config files marked as such, and the documentation for each package in question and go through the list what you want to keep.

Use

- `rpm -ql packagename` for listing the files
- `rpm -qc packagename` for listing the config files
- `rpm -qd packagename` for listing the documentation files

and go through those lists and manually create backups for files that should be configuration files but are not marked as such (i.e. that appear in `rpm -ql` output), as pointed out by @Jeff Schaller already.